# How to get the last hours in the interval of 5 mins in an array - MySQL timestamp format?

Tags: javascript

I did this

```
var date, lastTen = [];
date = new Date();

while (date.getMinutes() % interval !== 0) {
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 1 );
}

for (var i = 0; i < 24 * (60/interval); i++) {
    lastTen.push(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() - interval);
}

console.log(lastTen.slice(0,10));
```

I got

```
(10) ["17:5", "17:0", "16:55", "16:50", "16:45", "16:40", "16:35", "16:30", "16:25", "16:20"]
```

How do I turn those hour string to a mysql format ?

```
["2019-05-15 17:5:00", "2019-05-15 17:0:00", "2019-05-15 16:55:00", "2019-05-15 16:50:00", "2019-05-15 16:45:00", "2019-05-15 16:40:00", "2019-05-15 16:35:00", "2019-05-15 16:30:00", "2019-05-15 16:25:00", "2019-05-15 16:20"]
```

Comment: `dateString.toISOString().slice(0,10)` will get you the date part, so you can just prepend that to the string you push into the array. And you can hard code the `:00` at the end. BTW you might also want to pad those hours and minutes which are less than 10 with a leading zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just printed it "wrong" let's say. You needed the 0's before the hours, minutes and seconds. Also you needed the seconds

```
var date, lastTen = [];
date = new Date();

while (date.getMinutes() % interval !== 0) {
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 1 );
}

for (var i = 0; i < 24 * (60/interval); i++) {
    lastTen.push(date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getDate() + " " + (date.getHours()<10?'0':'') + date.getHours() + ':' + (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes() + ":" + (date.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + date.getSeconds());
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() - interval);
}

console.log(lastTen.slice(0,10));
```

Comment: your snippet has an error. Did you run it before posting?